# How can I run a C# program on my school's Linux server?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I would like to write a program in C# on Visual Studio on my windows computer and then upload it to my school's Linux server and run the program there. Assignments are turned in via this server: my professor receives the file and runs it from his directory. Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

I read about Mono but from my understanding of it, Mono is used to write and run C# applications on Linux so if it's not on my school's server then I would't be able to run the application. So even if I uploaded a copy of Mono to my personal directory on the server, my professor wouldn't be able to run the program from his directory. Is this correct?

I would like to know if there is any way to do this with or without Mono.

Edit: The professor will be running the program like this:

```
$p1 testfile
```

where "testfile" is a command line argument being passed to my program. "p1" will probably be a script that I'll write to run the program.

Comment: Does your assignment expect a deliverable written and built in C#?

Comment: No, the professor has no preference in terms of what language the program is written in. He just wants to be able to run the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest first checking to see if your school's Linux machines have mono already installed. Check the lib folder and see if there's a mono folder. The directory may not line up exactly, but it should be something along this line:

```
/usr/local/lib/mono/  ; various things here
```

If the school system doesn't have mono, I would ask the professor to have the system admin install mono on one or more machines. If that isn't possible then I would go down the route of packaging it yourself.

Check out the Mono project [here](http://www.mono-project.com/).

Comment: If the command line is accessible, I believe `which mono` should work as well.

Comment: ^True. If he/she is using Windows they should be able to use Putty to ssh into the Linux machine and test this from home (that is what I used to do) :)

Comment: Entering "which mono" gave me "/usr/bin/mono". Is this a green light?

Comment: I would make a small hello world program and test it out.

Comment: Great! So here's the plan: 1) Write program in VS 2) Copy/paste into mono 3)compile on mono 4) run using "$mono program". Does that sound right?  @Google: yes I will test it right away.

Comment: You should be able to load a Visual Studio solution in MonoDevelop and compile. You can also install/use Mono on Windows for testing purposes as well. If your professor is doing automated grading/checking/running then you can wrap the $mono prog.exe in a shell script so you don't break any automated stuff he/she does.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what he does. I had to write scripts before to compile and execute c and java programs so that his automated runs would work(to be fair, he showed us how to do this). I just installed Mono so I'll start testing now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Works on my computer and on the server. Case closed guys. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 4):

you can bundle your compiled application with the required runtime files so the app can be run without having a mono runtime installed, but you should test it out before giving it them and it would just be easier to have your professor install mono.

read: http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications

Comment: Bundling the app with the runtime sounds interesting, I'll try to check that out.